# C++ Ranged-based For Loop Efficiency

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, ranged-loops

When I started learning Java the first time, I remember thinking of how I wanted a for-each loop in C++; however, now that they have been added and I am (marginally) wiser than before, I have to wonder if they are actually more efficient?

There are two cases I am curious about, the first is the traditional array, and the second is a dynamic sized object, like the std::vector.

I would predict that iterating over a traditional fixed-size array would be more efficient with a for loop, and dynamically allocated storage would be faster with the range-based loop.

```
int fvalues[NUMBER];
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < NUMBER; ++x) {
    //Do Stuff
}

for(auto&& i : fvalues) {
    //Do Stuff
}


std::vector<int> dvalues = std::vector<int>(NUMBER);
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < NUMBER; ++x) {
    //Do Stuff (not adding or removing from vector)
}

for(auto&& i : dvalues) {
    //Do Stuff (not adding or removing from vector)
}
```

Comment: Instead predicting, benchmark it.

Comment: Why *should* one be more efficient than the other? Do you have any thoughts on the matter, or is this just a "gut feeling" of yours?

Comment: It's no slower than iterating through with iterators.

Comment: My suspicion is that the index of a fixed-size can be directly accessed based on the memory locations, but dynamic would have the possibility of jumping through pointers. This means that the current index would be faster with a dynamic type while it would be unnecessary overhead on a fixed size.

Comment: Such style of "I think this may be true.. let's ask SO on whether I am correct" is not what SO should be there for, I think. It's about problems and solutions. Your kind of query is more suitable for general discussion forums

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I understand your point, however the description of SO is, "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers," which is notably vague for what I believe to be a reason.

Comment: The question would be better suited if you benchmarked and asked something about the results of that benchmarking. Someone else could benchmark, or look at the assembly, and put that into an answer, but there's no reason you can't.

Comment: @chris I thought someone knew the answer already, but I am actually working on benchmarking it now.

Comment: @Chris Quote: "It's no slower than iterating through with iterators."
Well, an iterator is exactly what you use when doing a range based for loop...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Any difference is negligible at best. Using the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const size_t NUMBER = 1000000;

int main() {
    time_t start;
    time_t finish;


    int fvalues[NUMBER];


    time(&start);
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < NUMBER; ++x) {
        fvalues[x] = 3;
    }
    time(&finish);

    std::cout << "Fixed For: " << std::difftime(finish, start) << '\n';

    time(&start);
    for(auto&& i : fvalues) {
        i = 5;
    }
    time(&finish);
    std::cout << "Fixed Range: " << std::difftime(finish, start) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> dvalues;
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < NUMBER; ++x) {
        dvalues.push_back(0);
    }

    time(&start);
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < NUMBER; ++x) {
        dvalues[x] = 3;
    }
    time(&finish);
    std::cout << "Dynamic For: " << std::difftime(finish, start) << '\n';

    time(&start);
    for(auto&& i : dvalues) {
        i = 5;
    }
    time(&finish);
    std::cout << "Dynamic Range: " << std::difftime(finish, start) << '\n';
}
```

The result is always 0 for all tests. And timing the entire program (terminal time command) yields 0.033s of user time so the result is not surprising.

Comment: In all of your examples, the entire loop is going to be optimized away.

Comment: So super efficient then :))